# Showing marker for separate values only in line chart in HIghchart

Tags: highcharts

I'm drawing line chart using Highstock and I wonder if it is possible to add marker only to "separated" points (i.e. points without direct neighbours) in series. It is not possible to see these points if markers are disabled.

I mean data likes this:

```
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, null, 106.4, null, 144.0, 176.0, null, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    }]
```

If you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvCFD/ you'll see, that values for Jan and Mar are not visible without mouse hover. I don't want to enable markers globally for the whole data series. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable all markers, and prepare own function which recognise if markers has next element or not. Then show/hide appropriate svg elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/hvCFD/3/

```
 var data = chart.series[0].data,
        len = data.length,
        i = 0;
    for(i;i<len;i++) {

        if((typeof(data[i+1]) != "undefined") && (data[i+1].y!=null) && (data[i-1].y!=null) && (data[i].y!=null))
            data[i].graphic.destroy();
    }
```

Comment: This probably fits my needs best, it would be more problematic to prepare data before rendering in my case, thanks

Answer (score 3):

First you can disable all markers by the following code:

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just have to enable the markers you want(jan and mar).

```
series: [{
    data: [
    // january
    {
        y: 29.9,
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },

    null,

    // march
    {
        y: 106.4,
        marker: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },

    ...

}]
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aTwBk/)

Comment: As I commented under wergel's answer, I was hoping wor some thing automatic. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the `marker` properties per point. Not that you have to allow markers globally in the chart. See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/hvCFD/1/).

Sample code:

```
data: [{
                y: 29.9,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 2
                }
            }, {
                y: null,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },....
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that, I was just hopping there is some automatic option. I guess this will have to do.